# is it possible xslt transformation on the fly of php string

Tags: php, xml, xslt, curl, xml-parsing

I don't know if I am going about this right, i have a cURL script that pulls an xml from a feed then contains it within a php string $rawdata data looks like...

```
<search>
    <response status="1">
        <errors>
            <number_of_hotels>1 of 1</number_of_hotels>
        </errors>
    </response>
    <lr_rates>
        <hotel>
            <hotel_ref>142680</hotel_ref>
            <hotel_currency>GBP</hotel_currency>
            <hotel_rooms>
                <room>
                    <ref>4380316</ref>
                    <type>10</type>
                    <type_description>Apartment</type_description>
                    <sleeps>2</sleeps>
                    <rooms_available>0</rooms_available>
                    <adults>2</adults>
                    <children>0</children>
                    <breakfast>false</breakfast>
                    <dinner>false</dinner>
                    <description>The apartment has seperate kitchen area, lounge/dining area, bedroom with double bed and bathroom with bath &amp; shower.</description>
                    <alternate_description/>
                    <rack_rate>140.00</rack_rate>
                    <rate>
                        <date>31/07/2012</date>
                        <formatted_date>31 July 2012</formatted_date>
                        <price>Full</price>
                        <hotelcurrencyprice>Full</hotelcurrencyprice>
                        <numeric_price>Full</numeric_price>
                        <numeric_hotelcurrencyprice>Full</numeric_hotelcurrencyprice>
                        <requested_currency>GBP</requested_currency>
                    </rate>
                    <rate>
                        <date>01/08/2012</date>
                        <formatted_date>01 August 2012</formatted_date>
                        <price>Full</price>
                        <hotelcurrencyprice>Full</hotelcurrencyprice>
                        <numeric_price>Full</numeric_price>
                        <numeric_hotelcurrencyprice>Full</numeric_hotelcurrencyprice>
                        <requested_currency>GBP</requested_currency>
                    </rate>
                    <available_online>false</available_online>
                    <minimum_nights>1</minimum_nights>
                    <bed_type>Double</bed_type>
                    <cancellation_policy/>
                    <cancellation_days/>
                    <cancellation_hours/>
                    <room_terms/>
                </room>
                <room>
                    <ref>4383781</ref>
                    <type>10</type>
                    <type_description>Apartment</type_description>
                    <sleeps>4</sleeps>
                    <rooms_available>0</rooms_available>
                    <adults>4</adults>
                    <children>0</children>
                    <breakfast>false</breakfast>
                    <dinner>false</dinner>
                    <description>The apartment has seperate kitchen area, lounge with dining area, two double bedrooms, ensuite &amp; main bathroom.</description>
                    <alternate_description/>
                    <rack_rate>185.00</rack_rate>
                    <rate>
                        <date>31/07/2012</date>
                        <formatted_date>31 July 2012</formatted_date>
                        <price>Full</price>
                        <hotelcurrencyprice>Full</hotelcurrencyprice>
                        <numeric_price>Full</numeric_price>
                        <numeric_hotelcurrencyprice>Full</numeric_hotelcurrencyprice>
                        <requested_currency>GBP</requested_currency>
                    </rate>
                    <rate>
                        <date>01/08/2012</date>
                        <formatted_date>01 August 2012</formatted_date>
                        <price>Full</price>
                        <hotelcurrencyprice>Full</hotelcurrencyprice>
                        <numeric_price>Full</numeric_price>
                        <numeric_hotelcurrencyprice>Full</numeric_hotelcurrencyprice>
                        <requested_currency>GBP</requested_currency>
                    </rate>
                    <available_online>false</available_online>
                    <minimum_nights>1</minimum_nights>
                    <bed_type/>
                    <cancellation_policy/>
                    <cancellation_days/>
                    <cancellation_hours/>
                    <room_terms/>
                </room>
            </hotel_rooms>
            <cancellation_type>First Night Stay Chargeable</cancellation_type>
            <cancellation_policy>1 Days Prior to Arrival</cancellation_policy>
            <citytax>
                <typename/>
                <value/>
                <optedin/>
                <iscitytaxarea/>
            </citytax>
        </hotel>
    </lr_rates>
</search>
```

There are multiple instances of prices an other information that I need to pass back to the php if thats possible...........
..............ok so the answer is yes it is possible but now im stuck trying to get xsl to output the room data so this is how i got it working up to the point of getting output first i had to rebuilt my php install to include xsl, then used this php to call it all:

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 0;
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1)");
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
  $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->$rawdata;
   $xsl = new DOMDocument;
   $xsl->load('path/to/file.xsl');
   $proc = new XSLTProcessor();
   $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);
  $lrdata = $proc->transformToXML($xml);
```

that all works now but i cant get my xslt to pull the data from each room node ive tried changing the match and select values but no luck what am i doing wrong here assuming that the xml is the same as above this is the xsl:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <h2> Availability Search:</h2>
       <table border="1">
       <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <th align="left">Room Type</th>
        <th align="left">Description</th>
        <th align="left">Availability</th>
        <th align="left">Price</th>
        </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="/room">
       <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="type_description" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="description" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="rooms_available" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="rack_rate" /></td>
      </tr>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

sorry for confusion so now i need to know what am doing wrong with this xsl and if it is possible to pass information back to php as a $string

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What is your specific question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xsl:for-each select needs to read:

```
<xsl:for-each select='//room'>
```

The reason is that the /room would look for a room on the main level (and in XML you can only have 1), but //room looks for all room elements at any level in the XML tree.

The complete XSL: (you were also missing the xsl:output directive)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method='html' />
       <xsl:template match="/">
          <h2> Availability Search:</h2>
           <table border="1">
           <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <th align="left">Room Type</th>
            <th align="left">Description</th>
            <th align="left">Availability</th>
            <th align="left">Price</th>
            </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="//room">
           <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="type_description" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="description" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="rooms_available" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="rack_rate" /></td>
          </tr>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces 2 lines from your example

Comment: i tried that didnt work thanks for the help ive tried a few different xpath expressions that should have worked so i gues it could be the encoding

Answer (score 1):

i managed to get this working in the end the correct answer was, i was using dom where i should have been using simplexmlelement to create a XML after the curl that the xml comes in through thanks for your help

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $urlstring);
    $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
  $lrxml = new SimpleXMLElement($rawdata);
 $xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('path/to/file.xsl');
$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);
$lrdata = $proc->transformToXML($lrxml);
```